# How to use Laravel blade syntax in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-5.7

How to implement this syntax of `Laravel` below inside a `Vue.js` component?

```
@if(!Auth::guest())
    @if(Auth::user()->id === $post->user->id)
        <a href=#>edit</a>
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Laravel Blade is rendered on the server, but Vue.js runs in the browser. You need to provide the user's credentials to your Vue application in JavaScript so that it can know what to do. In order to help you do that, we need some more information about the structure of your application and if your Vue.js code has any kind of access control in it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This works now

```
<example-component :user="{{json_encode(Auth::user())}}"></example-component>
```

Exemple.vue

```
<template>
  <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
</template>export default {props : ['user']}
```